# Is there a specific command to run a project using Git cmd?

Tags: git, maven, open-source

I cloned an open-source project from GitHub. I have Git cmd and I know how to use it, but I wonder if there's a command to run the project from there. It's a maven project.

The project worked fine in Eclipse, but the frame wasn't exactly as the one in `README.md`. The last line of the application frame was omitted. So, I think there's a possibility to the frame to be the same as the one in that repository if I run it from the Git cmd.

Here are these three lines I found in `README.md` (I did step 1 and 2):

> 1. clone repo: https://github.com/stalk-calvin/tetris-game.git
> 2. `cd tetris-game`
> 3. run: `mvn install exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="tetris.Main"`

Any idea how to do step 3 above?

Comment: Git has nothing to do with this.  Do you have Maven installed?  I don’t understand the question.  You ran the first two commands, what is stopping you from running the third one?

Comment: @JimGarrison ((clone and cd )) are commands which are applied in Git cmd. I don't know how to apply the third one there too. But if it doesn't have anything to do with the Git cmd then it's fine.

Comment: @JimGarrison And yeah, I have Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The git cmd can rewrite `%PATH%` in order to include `git`.
But that means maven might not be included in said `PATH`.

First, you don't have to stay in a Git CMD session. You can perform the maven step in a regular CMD shell.

Make sure you have:

- java in your `PATH` (does `java -version` work?)
- [download maven](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) anywhere you want
- The user environment variable `M2_HOME` defined (referencing the folder where you have download maven)
- a PATH with %M2_HOME%\bin added to it
- `mvn -version` working.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it. But, even after I understood your answer. I still don't know what is the command I have to write to execute the project

Comment: The one in step 3